# Copy .mdf and log .ldf and then restore

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

SQL Server Express Local DB

I have a form with a button and when the button is clicked, I want to be able to copy the database to the `SaveFileDialog` location chosen by the user.

I have a `.MDF` for embedded database and the instance is not running, I can just copy `.MDF` and `.LDF` to back up. But how to do it? I tried with SQL commands but since it is an embedded database and the instance is not running how to copy?

```
 connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Expert-Pro-SoftDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: Um...[File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Yes, thank you and the restore? To overwrite the existing(current db) with the copied one?

Comment: Ok, thank you marc_s, is the good thing to File.Copy the .mdf and .ldf and then on another button restore them, copy them back in the application and overwrite the existing ?